# not able to install Ubuntu on Aquaris E4.5 which has android OS

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am not able to install Ubuntu on my Aquaris E4.5
I followed this link
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

anyone has link where i can follow and complete this installation

i follow the instruction from the above link. 
Till "Unlock the Android device" was fine then i did 
`$ fastboot reboot` and mobile goes on fastboot. then i type command

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --recovery-image home/recovery.img
```

Then it says waiting and device 1 not found

I doownload recovery.img  from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Comment: Well what happens? You're not giving us much information about the reason you can't install.

Comment: Please find above updated question